# Duplicating work in Next.js context is there a better way?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have been working on a navbar component in Next.JS and am finding that I am repeating myself when it feels like I shouldn't. I am creating and using a React context. and find that I need to define an `Array<object>` in both the app.tsx and Context.tsx files.

In my Context.tsx I need to pass in the navbarJSON value into my `createContext()` function This means that I house the object in this file.

```js
interface navItem {
  label: string,
  itemType: string,
  position: number,
  largeDropdown?: Array<any> | null
}

const navbarJSON: Array<navItem> = [
  {
    label: "About us",
    itemType: "single",
    position: 2,
    largeDropdown: null
  },
  .
  .
  .
]

const NavbarContext = createContext(navbarJSON)
```

And then in my app.tsx I house the same navbarJSON and interface so I can pass it as a variable into my `ContextWrappe`

```js
interface navItem {
  label: string,
  itemType: string,
  position: number,
  largeDropdown?: Array<any> | null
}

const navbarJSON: Array<navItem> = [
  {
    label: "About us",
    itemType: "single",
    position: 2,
    largeDropdown: null
  },
  .
  .
  .
]

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
  <>
    <ContextWrapper navigation={navbarJSON}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ContextWrapper>
    
  </>
  )
}
```

If I set the `createContext()` to null the linter will not get the proper types downstream in the navbar component. I'll get errors that say **Object is possibly 'null'** warnings

My question is if there is a better way that I can define my context to allow me to not have to define my data in two places? Ill be in the comments if you guys have any other questions.

Kind Regards!

**Update 06/07/2022**

@juliomalves asked why I need to give the object to the __app.tsx file if I set a default value in my context. This is because the context wrapper component takes in the value of navigation and then passes the prop to the `NavbarContext.Provider` as seen below. It was a part of the code I forgot to add to my question my apologies.

Without passing a value the provider gives me an error:

`Property 'value' is missing in type '{ children: any; }' but required in type 'ProviderProps<navItem[]>'`

```js
function ContextWrapper({children, navigation} : any) {
  
  const [menuItems] = useState(navigation);

  return (
    <NavbarContext.Provider value={menuItems}>
      {children}
    </NavbarContext.Provider>
  )

};
```

When I tried his recommendation to type createContext and initialize it as null I got this error saying that I cant initialize it as null because it is expecting a value of `navItem[]`

`Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'navItem[]'`

Comment: As a workaround, I create a directory named data with a file NavbarData.tsx. In that file, I export the navbarJSON array and import the file into both the context.tsx and app.tsx. That seems to be more organized. I'm still open to any better suggestions.

Comment: If you're passing the object to `createContext()` to set it as the default value, why do you need to pass it in `_app`?

Comment: Note that you can also type `createContext` accordingly and still initialize it as `null`, i.e `createContext<Array<navItem>>(null)`.

Comment: @juliomalves I updated my question to answer why I pass the object to _app and also tried to type `createContext` but got an error. Thanks for your help but It still seems I need to pass the object in two places.